# Database attach method for big content database size

Tags: 2010, migration

I have one site collection with multiple sub sites and planned to migrate from SP 2010 to 2016?

I checked the content database size that is about 1.5 tera!!
The third party tool is not option, Is it allowed to migrate it using database attach method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, though expect it to take some time. Remember you have to first upgrade to 2013, convert to claims, upgrade the sites to V15 mode, then upgrade to 2016.